# How to config the sc in spark?

Tags: pyspark

```
myConf = SparkConf().setAppName("create_h5_pairwise")\
             .set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", False)\
             .set("spark.akka.frameSize", 300)\
             .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize","8G")\
             .set("spark.num.executors", 40)\
             .set("spark.executor.memory", "20G")\
             .set("spark.executor.cores", 3)\
             .set("spark.driver.memory", "4G")
sc = SparkContext(conf=myConf)
```

I have successfully use this config of sc to read a small table from hive (500 rows).
Now I want to change the sc configure to read a table with more than 600 million rows. How to configure the sc parameters ? 
I use the same sc to read the huge table ? When I count it, it stuck in the following phase:

```
[Stage 11:>                                                         (0 + 2) / 4]
```

And there is no progress at all.

Comment: How do you run the application? It looks like started in `local` mode, not `yarn`.

Comment: in the pyspark interactive environment.

Comment: AFAIR, if you use pyspark interactive repl, then you should pass parameters in commendline, like: `--num-executors 40 --conf spark.driver.memory 4g`, etc. Please try it out, and remember to set `--mode yarn-client`